# solve expo init appname fail cont generation app

Tags: react-native

when I try  runs the code expo init "name app" it will case some error and don't initiation the project

? Choose a template: (Use arrow keys)
  ----- Managed workflow -----

> blank         minimal dependencies to run and an empty root component
>     tabs          several example screens and tabs using react-navigation
>     ----- Bare workflow -----
>     bare-minimum  minimal setup for using unimodules

PS F:> expo init ap
? Choose a template: (Use arrow keys)
  ----- Managed workflow -----

> blank         minimal dependencies to run and an empty root component
>     tabs          several example screens and tabs using react-navigation
>     ----- Bare workflow -----
>     bare-minimum  minimal setup for using unimodules

Answer (score 0):

**Select the first "blank" option. Its will provide you the basic template of JavaScript language**
https://itnext.io/set-up-react-native-with-expo-1e63a82d01ac